# handling multiple servers of socket.io by redis-adapter

Tags: redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe, node-redis

I have 2 servers (clone of each other) running socket.io server (ws01, ws02) and I used redis-adapter to handle the events between them. Note: The redis server is running on a separate server (Third Server).

I have tried to connect 4 websocket postman as clients, the first 2 clients are connected to ws01 and the second 2 clients are connected to ws02. All 4 clients are joined to the same room (room1)

The problem is when I emit a message from any client to the room, the message is sent to only to the clients that on the same server.

Here is my ws server code

```
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const { createClient } = require('redis');
const { createAdapter } = require('@socket.io/redis-adapter');

const io = new Server();

const client = createClient({ url: 'redis://REDIS_SERVER_IP:6379' });

(async () => {
    await client.connect();
})();

client.on('connect', () => console.log('::> Redis Client Connected'));
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('<:: Redis Client Error', err));

const pubClient = client;
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();


io.adapter(createAdapter(pubClient, subClient));


io.use(function(socket, next){
  if (socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token){
    if (socket.handshake.query.token === "12345"){
      next();
    }else{
       next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    }
    
  }
  else {
    next(new Error('Authentication error'));
  }    
}).on("connection", (socket) => {

  console.log("device connected");

  socket.join("room1");


  io.to("room1").emit("message", "Hi all");

});


io.listen(3000);
```

Also I have double checked the redis server by redis-cli ->> MONITOR
I saw it caches the message correctly for example

```
1688152060.540409 [0 SENDER_SERVER_IP:60014] "PUBLISH" "socket.io#/#room1#" "\x93\xa6ogouXP\x83\xa4type\x02\xa4data\x92\xa7message\xa6Hi all\xa3nsp\xa1/\x83\xa5rooms\x91\xa5room1\xa6except\x90\xa5flags\x80"
```

Note I haven’t saw a subscribe event on (redis-cli ->> MONITOR). Always PUBLISH like the example above. I don’t know if this has something related to the problem or not